# Contact form 7 dropdown not working

Tags: contact-form-7

All of a sudden my drop down lists in Contact Form 7 are not working and cannot for the life of me figure it out. there are two spots where this happens as you can see in the form.

I have already looked into the code but no idea

http://www.aimbookingagency.com/offer-form/

its not listing them all and the box is SUPER tall. I am not a form expert by ANY means so I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the problem but I re created the problem sections "SELECT dropdown menus" and it seemed to format fine. So I deleted the bad versions.

not sure if this will help anyone in the future.